# Pause Windows 11 updates with powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-11

I am referring to the PowerShell script to pause windows 10 updates up to 35 days [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62424065).

It states  to pause windows 10 updates via powershell write this:

```sh
$pause = (Get-Date).AddDays(35)
$pause = $pause.ToUniversalTime().ToString( "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" )
$pause_start = (Get-Date)
$pause_start = $pause_start.ToUniversalTime().ToString( "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" )
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings' -Name 'PauseUpdatesExpiryTime' -Value $pause                                                                                        
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings' -Name 'PauseFeatureUpdatesStartTime' -Value $pause_start
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings' -Name 'PauseFeatureUpdatesEndTime' -Value $pause
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings' -Name 'PauseQualityUpdatesStartTime' -Value $pause_start
Set-itemproperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings' -Name 'PauseQualityUpdatesEndTime' -Value $pause
```

This doesn't work in Windows 11. Does anybody knows what doesn't work and why?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I went to check what happens when I pause the updates manually. Actually there Is one more key which is added, with the name "PauseUpdatesStartTime".
So I tried the powershell script with this key and it worked. Now the corrected script looks like:

```
$pause = (Get-Date).AddDays(35)
$pause = $pause.ToUniversalTime().ToString( "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" )
$pause_start = (Get-Date)
$pause_start = $pause_start.ToUniversalTime().ToString( "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" )
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings' -Name 'PauseUpdatesExpiryTime' -Value $pause                                                                                        
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings' -Name 'PauseFeatureUpdatesStartTime' -Value $pause_start
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings' -Name 'PauseFeatureUpdatesEndTime' -Value $pause
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings' -Name 'PauseQualityUpdatesStartTime' -Value $pause_start
Set-itemproperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings' -Name 'PauseQualityUpdatesEndTime' -Value $pause
Set-itemproperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings' -Name 'PauseUpdatesStartTime' -Value $pause_start
New-Item -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU' -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path  'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU' -Name 'NoAutoUpdate' -PropertyType DWORD -Value 1
```

To execute the ps script via cmd, I jut need to write this:

```
> powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted C:\path_to_my_script\pausewin11upd.ps1
```